# Getting a segmentation fault in c

Tags: c, colors, segmentation-fault

So this function is to change the region in an image to a certain color.  But when I ran this code, it gave me a segmentation fault.  I don't know why it keeps giving me this error.  Would anybody be able to help me out?  Here is my code:

```
void region_set( uint8_t array[], 
         unsigned int cols, 
         unsigned int rows,
         unsigned int left,
         unsigned int top,
         unsigned int right,
         unsigned int bottom,
         uint8_t color )
{   
    for (int x = 0; x < ((right-left)*(top-bottom)); x++)
    {
        array[x] = color;
    }
}
```

Comment: What values have you passed in and how is array initialized?

Comment: I passed in (array, 256, 256, 0, 50, 50, 0, 255)

Comment: A good guess would be that your array size is too small for your input parameters.

Comment: Also, this code won't do what you want it to: you aren't using the cols or rows parameters, which are necessary for knowing how far into array[] you need to access to get the right column.

Comment: Compile *all your program* with *all warnings and debug info* (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) then **use the debugger** (`gdb`) -and [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) if available. The bug is probably in the caller.

Comment: Yeah right now, I have a Makefile that has the gcc -Wall and -g embedded.  But it didn't say any errors about that

Comment: It's strange that `top` is 50 and `bottom` is 0 but it looks like your code is expecting that.  Still, you should make sure your inputs are correct otherwise you might subtract and get a negative number.  Also, you are recoloring the top of your image instead of a rectangle within the image.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the size if "array[]" is less than "((right-left)*(top-bottom))",